# How to use cleaned_data before form validation condition?

Tags: python, django

I wanted to use cleaned_data['username'] before form.is_valid() condition as shown in the code. I want to get the value from Django form field and check in database if the username exist or not. But its giving me error " Form object has no attribute cleaned_data" how should I solve this or is there any other way to get value from Django form?

view.py

```
def RegistrationView(request):
    form=Registration_Form()
    
    if request.method=='POST':
        print("In Post")
        form=Registration_Form(request.POST)
        username=form.cleaned_data['username']
        print(username)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            form.save()
            return redirect('login_view')
        else:
            # messages.error(request,"Form is Invalid!")
            return redirect('registration_view')

    else:
        return render(request,'registration.html',{'form':form})
```

model.py

```
class User_Registration(models.Model):
    company_name=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=False)
    username=models.CharField(max_length=10,primary_key=True,unique=True,blank=False)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True,blank=False)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=250,blank=False)
```

forms.py

```
class Registration_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User_Registration
        fields=('company_name','username','password','email')

        widgets={
            'company_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control input-sm'}),
            'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'password':forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'email':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.POST.get('username')`  to access raw post data.

```
class Registration_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_username(self):
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        # do your validation here
        # and return the data
```